# How to refresh page after deleting item in React reduxjs/toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using:

- React 17.0.2
- TypeScript 4.5.2
- @reduxjs/toolkit: 1.6.2

After deleting item (for me it's wordSet) i need to update my UI. For now after item is deleting only from database and to update UI i must refresh the page.

Could you tell me how i should make item delete from UI?
I could use wordSets.filter to return new array, but it is good way?

My code:

```
export const deleteWordSet = createAsyncThunk<void, string>(
  'wordSet/deleteWordSet',
  async (id: string, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const accessToken = getToken();
      if (!accessToken) thunkAPI.rejectWithValue('Invalid token');
      const config = {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
      };
      await api.delete(`/wordSet/${id}`, config);
    } catch (error) {
      thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);


export const fetchWordSets = createAsyncThunk<IWordSet[]>(
  'wordSet/fetchWordSets',
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const accessToken = getToken();
      if (!accessToken) thunkAPI.rejectWithValue('Invalid token');
      const config = {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
      };
      const response: IApiResponse<IWordSet[]> = await api.get('/wordSet', config);
      const data = response.data.data;
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);



const WordSetList = () => {
  const { wordSets } = useAppSelector(state => state.wordSet);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchWordSets()).unwrap();
  }, [dispatch]);
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {wordSets.map(wordSet => (
        <WordSetListItem key={wordSet._id} {...wordSet} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default WordSetList;
```

According to Jamal's hints made some changes

Now on my asynthunk i'm returning deleted word's id then filtering data if delete Workset is fulfilled.

```
builder.addCase(deleteWordSet.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
  state.isFetching = false;
  state.wordSets = state.wordSets.filter(wordSet => wordSet._id !== action.payload);
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to refresh page?

Comment: Because in every component rerender i'm fetching wordSets

Comment: If you update the reducer properly by returning the updated data, your UI will be updated, otherwise, your need to reload the page manually

Comment: @Jamal what do you mean by saying "if you update the reducer properly by returning the updated data"  How to properly delete item from state and database? Should i use filter method?

Comment: I mean you send the updated data as payload, and from there update the state of your reducer according to the passed payload. I think the problem is in your reducer and the return seciton

Comment: @Jamal i updated my code. Now when i remove the item, it is removed also from ui. Is this good approach?

Comment: It looks good and you can improve it, and remember you need to pass updated data to your reducers to perform any UI change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to pass the updated data to your reducer so the UI will get updated without refresh. Send the updated data as payload, and from there update the state of your reducer according to the passed payload.